# Exchange 2007 microsoft-server-activesync requires credentials internally

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, ssl-certificate

We've got a proper DigiCert wildcard certificate which appears to be set up properly on Exchange 2007.

The Microsoft test site https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/ passes without any problems as does Test-OwaConnectivity & Test-OutlookWebServices internally.

Our problem is that internal Outlook users keep getting a message asking if they'd allow Autodiscover to configure Outlook and then a popup asking for credentials. If the user ticks a box to allow the autodiscover service to configure Outlook always, they still get the popup every time they open Outlook.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What type of outlook version are you using?
Outlook 2003 works different from Outlook 2007/2010.

Can you please specify the credentials settings for OwaVirtualDirectory and Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync directory.

I would also point out the need of correct InternalUrl and ExternalUrl.

By the way, microsoft-server-activesync is only for mobile devices, not for Outlook clients!

Comment: We are using Outlook 2010. Isn't microsoft-server-activesync what autodiscover uses? Perhaps that is where I'm going wrong. :-)

You wish to know the IIS Authentication for OWA & Activesync? Apologies if I've gotten that wrong. They both have Basic & Windows Authentication enabled, but nothing else. Thanks.